# MongoDB using $map $group with condition using aggregate function

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

I have a collection **funds** and **fundtransaction** querying balances and sum base on transaction methods and type. Query below getting right result adding balances, but I have a problem with grouping and projecting results.

And also I just want to improve my query using $map and projected those fields that I want to display

**funds Collection**

```
"funds": [
   {
     "_id": ObjectId("623dd490c00eec15c805920b"),
     balance: 160
   }
]
```

**FundTransactions Collection**

```
  "fundTransactions": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("623dd490c00eec15c805921a"),
      "fundID": ObjectId("623dd490c00eec15c805920b"),
      "transactionMethods": "Cash",
      "transactionType": "Deposit",
      "amount": 100
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("623dd490c00eec15c805931f"),
      "fundID": ObjectId("623dd490c00eec15c805920b"),
      "transactionMethods": "EBT",
      "transactionType": "Deposit",
      "amount": 20
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("623dd490c00eec15c805733d"),
      "fundID": ObjectId("623dd490c00eec15c805920b"),
      "transactionMethods": "Cash",
      "transactionType": "Expense",
      "amount": 10
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("623dd490c00eec15c805733c"),
      "fundID": ObjectId("623dd490c00eec15c805920b"),
      "transactionMethods": "Debit Card",
      "transactionType": "Deposit",
      "amount": 50
    },
  ]
```

**Aggregate Function**

```
db.funds.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "fundTransactions",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "fundID",
      "as": "funds"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$funds"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "funds": "$funds.transactionMethods"
      },
      "totalBalance": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$eq": [
                "$funds.transactionType",
                "Deposit"
              ]
            },
            "$funds.amount",
            {
              "$multiply": [
                "$funds.amount",
                -1.0
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "Expense": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$eq": [
                "$funds.transactionType",
                "Expense"
              ]
            },
            "$funds.amount",
            0.0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "EBT": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$eq": [
              "$_id.funds",
              "EBT"
            ]
          },
          {
            "$round": [
              "$totalBalance",
              0.0
            ]
          },
          0.0
        ]
      },
      "Cash": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$eq": [
              "$_id.funds",
              "Cash"
            ]
          },
          {
            "$round": [
              "$totalBalance",
              0.0
            ]
          },
          0.0
        ]
      },
      "Debit Card": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$eq": [
              "$_id.funds",
              "Debit Card"
            ]
          },
          {
            "$round": [
              "$totalBalance",
              0.0
            ]
          },
          0.0
        ]
      },
      "Expense": {
        "$round": [
          "$Expense",
          0.0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0.0,
      "totalBalance": 0.0
    }
  }
])
```

**This is my current output using this query**

```
[
  {
    "Cash": 90,
    "Debit Card": 0,
    "EBT": 0,
    "Expense": 10
  },
  {
    "Cash": 0,
    "Debit Card": 0,
    "EBT": 20,
    "Expense": 0
  },
  {
    "Cash": 0,
    "Debit Card": 50,
    "EBT": 0,
    "Expense": 0
  }
]
```

**My expected output, should group transaction methods and display single result**

```
  {
    "Cash": 90,
    "Debit Card": 50,
    "EBT": 20,
    "TotalExpense": 10
  },
```

You can see [result here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JBGyoWGibp6)

Comment: Looks like you just need to group and sum the output: https://mongoplayground.net/p/hXeIOrLfoo9

Answer (score 0):

You just need to append this to the end of your aggregate function:

```
(...)
  {
     "$project": {
       "_id": 0.0,
       "totalBalance": 0.0
     }
  },
  {
     $group: {
       _id: "Total",
       Cash: {
         $sum: "$Cash"
       },
       "Debit Card": {
         $sum: "$Debit Card"
       },
       EBT: {
         $sum: "$EBT"
       },
       Expense: {
         $sum: "$Expense"
       },
       TotalExpense: {
         $sum: "$TotalExpense"
       }
     }
  }
```